# flutter firestore paginate results

Tags: flutter

```
bool hasMore = true;
bool isLoading = false;
DocumentSnapshot nextDocument;
DocumentSnapshot previousDocument;

getProducts() async {  
   if (!hasMore) {  
     print('No More Products');  
     return;  
   }  
   if (isLoading) {  
     return;  
   }  
   setState(() {  
     isLoading = true;  
   });  
   QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;  
   if (nextDocument == null) {  // First time to get products
     querySnapshot = await firestore  
         .collection('products')  
         .orderBy('name')  
         .limit(10)  
         .getDocuments();  
   } else {  
     querySnapshot = await firestore  
         .collection('products')  
         .orderBy('name')  
         .startAfterDocument(nextDocument)  
         .limit(10)  
         .getDocuments();  
     print(1);  
   }  
   if (querySnapshot.documents.length < 10) {  
     hasMore = false;  
   }  
   nextDocument = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.documents.length - 1]; 
  previousDocument = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.documents.length - 19];
   products.addAll(querySnapshot.documents);  
   setState(() {  
     isLoading = false;  
   });  
 }
```

try to use this code i don't do this before but i just try to help youtry to use this code i don't do this before but i just try to help youtry to use this code i don't do this before but i just try to help youtry to use this code i don't do this before but i just try to help youtry to use this code i don't do this before but i just try to help youtry to use this code i don't do this before but i just try to help youtry to use this code i don't do this before but i just try to help you